# How can we download Google Material Design Color Palettes?

Tags: color, resource-recommendations, google-material-design

I've seen many users in YouTube tutorials that use Google's color palettes (see link below) for design in Illustrator. I searched similar things in Google search but found old links that don't have any download link now. Can it be that Google removed those links? Is there any other resource to download the color palette for Photoshop and Illustrator?

https://www.materialui.co/colors

Comment: [This](https://material.io/) could be interesting. In Tools see the [Color Tool](https://material.io/tools/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0)

Comment: But it doesn't have option to download the palette.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Download link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1x_Ir5oTDzBIN8yBsHtPe_mTXks3oIUOO?usp=sharing

Update: added MaterialUI.ase file for illustrator.

You can open swatches in Illustrator: Swatches >> Open swatch library >> Other library >> Select downloaded file >> Done

[image]

Last update: Link updated, you can find all format swatches for adobe photoshop and illustrator.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the material design theme editor plugin that comes with the pallets built in. It works for the Sketch app.

Link: https://material.io/tools/theme-editor/

Screenshot:[image: example of library from the Theme Editor for Material Design]

Comment: I need it for Photoshop and Illustrator.

Comment: Hannah Milan (https://dribbble.com/hannahmilan) did a very good job for Adobe XD pallet (https://www.xdguru.com/material-color-palette-xd/), I think it could work with other Adobe Softwares as well.

Comment: I transformed the XD pallet into an Illustrator File(https://www.dropbox.com/s/bv72kypm1grzqzc/Material%20Design%20Color%20Pallette.ai?dl=0) I hope it helps you.